# g_io_channel and FIFO causes CPU to peg to 100%

Tags: c, gtk, glib, fifo

I'm trying to understand why my CPU pegs to 100% when I use a FIFO in conjunction with g_io_channel.

I have a project on [github](https://github.com/bertput/gio_fifo_client_server) that demonstrates the problem with the smallest possible setup; just a simple server that opens a FIFO in /tmp, and a client that sends a message to the server via that FIFO.

I found:

1. When first started, the server takes close to zero CPU
2. As soon as the client sends a message to the server via the FIFO, the message is received and printed by the server, and then the CPU goes to 100%.
3. You can continue to send messages via the FIFO and the server will print them, but that CPU stays at 100% :-/

I've tried the usual google, and stack overflow, but so far no joy on finding a solution.  I hope someone can help me understand what's going on.  I believe I am using glib/GTK correctly, but I'm quite happy to stand corrected.  I appreciate any help you can provide.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried profiling the application using a profiling tool (or just interrupting it with `gdb` a few times and seeing what the backtrace looks like)?

Comment: I reproduced your problem and indeed the program is stuck in the GTK+ main loop. You should install the debugging packages for GTK+ on your distro and run your server in gdb to check what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running the server using `strace`, I saw it was just calling `poll()` in a loop while returning the `POLLHUP` event. The problem seemed to be that you expect to be able to wait indefinitely for `G_IO_IN` events, to tell you data is coming, but don't manage `G_IO_HUP` that tell you that the connection was closed.

I then found this comment in [bluez code](https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez/blob/master/profiles/input/suspend-dummy.c#L57):

```
if (cond & (G_IO_ERR | G_IO_HUP)) {
        /*
         * Both ends needs to be open simultaneously before proceeding
         * any input or output operation. When the remote closes the
         * channel, hup signal is received on this end.
         */
        fifo_open();
        return FALSE;
}
```

This SO question explains it all: [Poll() on Named Pipe returns with POLLHUP constantly and immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021253/poll-on-named-pipe-returns-with-pollhup-constantly-and-immediately)

And that's what I saw with `strace`: when the client process exit (yours or just a simple `echo` to your fifo), the IO channel is notified that the other side of the connection hanged up. Your client currently sends a message and closes the connection. So either you want it to keep the connection alive and not disconnect, or you need to reopen the fifo server-side and add a new watch, or as says mark4o in the SO question I linked, [you open the fifo with read/write rights server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22023610/518853) so that you always have at least one writer on the fifo (the server), avoiding the hang up.

As an example, the bluez code I linked to closes the channel and opens a new one upon disconnection. Be careful to also take care of the reference counting issues on your code.

Comment: Hi @liberforce, thank you for your help!

I did try to post a stack trace from GDB in comments but the comment kept coming out wrapped instead of formatted as code.

The upshot, as you observed, is that the server is stuck in  __poll_nocancel () inside the main loop.  Since I intend to run the client multiple times while the server stays running, I will try opening the FIFO as read/write on the server to see if it fixes the problem.

Thank you!  I'll mark this as correct answer once I try your suggestion.

Comment: Problem solved by opening FIFO as O_RDWR on server.  Selected as correct answer.  Thank you!